# How to make scrolling inside section work with FullPageJs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullpage.js

I am trying to use FullPageJs and make scrolling inside section work but even though i have added the slim scroll pluging as recommended, the page does not scroll on desktop.

Here is the code i am using

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="../vendors/scrolloverflow.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../vendors/jquery.slimscroll.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="../jquery.fullPage.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="examples.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#fullpage').fullpage({
                anchors: ['firstPage', 'secondPage', '3rdPage', '4thPage'],
                sectionsColor: ['#4A6FB1', '#939FAA', '#323539'],
                scrollOverflow: true,
                scrollOverflowOptions: {
                    scrollbars: true,
                    mouseWheel: true,
                    hideScrollbars: false,
                    fadeScrollbars: false,
                    disableMouse: true
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
```

The page does not move on desktop and here is a [demo](http://usefaith.voiedusucces.net/fullpagemaster/examples/scrolling.html). The page only moves when i change disableMouse to false but then it moves only as though it is on mobile. I have to click and scroll.

**Question**

How to make scrolling inside section work normally with this ?

Answer (score 0):

You have [an example available in the files that comes with the download of fullpage.js](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js/blob/master/examples/scrolling.html).

And the same one [online](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/examples/scrolling.html).

fullpage.js doesn't use slimScroll.js anymore as you can see in the documentation:

> **scrollOverflow:** (default false) defines whether or not to create a scroll for the section/slide in case its content is bigger than the height of it. When set to true, your content will be wrapped by the plugin. Consider using delegation or load your other scripts in the afterRender callback. In case of setting it to true, it requires the vendor library scrolloverflow.min.js and it should be loaded before the fullPage.js plugin. For example:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="vendors/scrolloverflow.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.fullPage.js"></script>
```

> The page only moves when i change disableMouse to false

You don't have to modify any scrolloverflow option. Remove your `scrollOverflowOptions` if you want the default behavior.

Comment: That is exactly problem. Please try to scroll the page on desktop and you will see that it is not scrolling in the example you just gave me at 
http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/examples/scrolling.html
It is not scrolling on desktop both with Mozilla firefox 47.0.1 on windows and Chrome. But it scrolls on mobile.

Comment: It scrolls perfectly in the latest Firefox and Chrome for Windows. You can test it in Browserstack if you prefer. Nobody has complained about this anyway so chances are the problem is in your side.

Comment: Really even Browserstack is not scrolling on my windows 10 and everything works perfectly on my windows 10 except these.

Comment: I also have the same problem. It works on IE on windows 10 but not on Mozilla or Chrome or Opera. I also have windows 10 pro 64 bits

Comment: The normal scrolling option works perfectly but NOT Scrolling inside sections. Any help will be appreciated

Comment: I'm sorry, I can not reproduce your issue in any of the browsers and OS you  mentioned. Scrolling inside sections works perfectly for me in Windows 10 in Chrome and Opera and any other browser and OS I tried.